# how to evalute this equality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I want to prove this equality $$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{(x-y)\cdot y}{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}= \frac{ab}{4\pi}\frac{1}{a^2\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)+b^2\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)}.\tag{1}$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2)=(a\cos(\alpha),b\sin(\alpha)),y=(y_1,y_2)=(a\cos(\beta),b\sin(\beta))$ , $(x-y)\cdot y=(x_1-y_1)y_1+(x_2-y_2)y_2,$ and $x,y$ are two elements of the ellipse:
$$E=\left\{(x_1,x_2)~\middle|~\frac{x_1^2}{ a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}=1\right\}=\left\{(a\cos(\theta),b\sin(\theta))\,\middle|\,0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi\right\},$$

I used the trigonomtry formulas
 $$\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\beta)=-2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)$$
 $$\sin(\alpha)-\sin(\beta)=2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)$$

Can anyone help me.

related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1639486/244803)

Comment: what exactly has this to do with integration?

Comment: @tired, probably a change of variables in a double integral... (But I agree with you)

Comment: I want to evalute the integral over an ellipse, for example if we have the fundamantal solution of Laplace equation ($\Delta \Phi =\delta \quad in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$) of the form $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})$ then $$\nabla_y \Phi(x-y)\cdot n_y=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{(x-y)\cdot y}{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$$ where $n_y$ is the outward normal to the ellipse at the point $y$ and $$\int_{\partial E}\nabla \Phi(x-y)\cdot n_y\mathrm{d}y= \frac{ab}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a^2\sin^2(\alpha+ \beta )+b^2\cos^2(\alpha+ \beta )}\mathrm{d}\beta $$